# Herança com TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, herança, orm, typeorm

Existe problemas comuns que vejo muita dificuldade de se tratar com ORMs, e desconhecendo uma maneira nativa resolvi perguntar qual a melhor maneira de se tratar desses utilizando o TypeORM em projeto. Hoje eu tenho um projeto que trata com generalização e especialização de pessoa, basicamente eu tenho uma table `Pessoa` onde eu armazeno o `id` ou matricula, crio relações com números telefonicos, emails e endereços, e tenho outras duas tabelas que herdam a chave primaria de pessoa que é a `pessoa_juridica` e `pessoa_fisica`,  tendo em mente que minha aplicação trabalha com esses dois tipos de pessoa. O problema está em como eu devo implementar isso utilizando um ORM como o TypeORM?

Para ficar mais explicito o modelo:

[image: DER representando exemplo citado]

na imagem nós temos:

1. Uma relação `1-N` da tabela `pessoa` para tabela `telefone`
2. Uma relação `1-N` da tabela `pessoa` para tabela `email`
3. Uma relação `1-1` da tabela `pessoa` para tabela `pessoa_fisica`
4. Uma relação `1-1` da tabela `pessoa` para tabela `pessoa_juridica`

A questão ai está também em, uma pessoa física não pode ser pessoa jurídica ao mesmo tempo e vice e versa.

Comment: embora tenha um ponto objetivo na sua pergunta, parte dela pode se baseada em opiniões, e sinceramente uma entidade com 1 atributo não faz sentido, na minha humilde opinião ok? poderia levar o atributo "nome" para lá, e remover o "nome" e "nomed_fantasi", ai faria sentido. Agora *"uma pessoa física não pode ser pessoa jurídica ao mesmo tempo"* isso é resolvido pelo próprio modelo certo? uma PF não tem CNPJ nem Inscrição, assim como uma PJ não tem CPF nem RG. Mas já pesquisou sobre o `@TableInheritance` e `@ChildEntity`? Eles devem resolver o problema de implementação desse modelo

Comment: Isso Ricardo, na verdade estou montando uma api para um banco já existente e ele está modelado dessa meneira, por isso dei o exemplo, basicamente a entidade pessoa só guarda os ids, e as entidades de pessoa fisica e pessoa jurica herdam esses ids como pk, as outras entidades como telefone e email por exemplo estção relacionados com pessoa, logo as entidades filha herdam essas relações

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo bem simples, vou mandar 1-N de Telefone e 1-1 PJ e só replicar adicionar os outros relacionamentos. Espero que fique simples de entender

```
@Entity()
export class Pessoa {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number

 @OneToMany(() => Telefone, telefone => telefone.pessoa)
 telefones: Telefone[]
}


@Entity()
export class Telefone {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number

 @ManyToOne(() => Pessoa, pessoa => pessoa.telefones)
 pessoa: Pessoa
}


@Entity()
export class PJ {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number

 @OneToOne(() => Pessoa)
 @JoinColumn()
 pessoa: Pessoa
}
```

PS: Importar os decorators do TypeORM e também cada entity que for utilizar. Se usa Pessoa no PJ, importar a entity Pessoa no arquivo do PJ.

Doc: https://typeorm.io/#/relations

Comment: A minha questão Guilherme, é que utilizando as relações comuns, o a gente interpreta que Pessoa tem uma Pessoa Fisica e não que Pessoa Fisica é uma pessoa, entende? A questão toda se baseia ai, por isso queria saber como o TypeORM se relaciona com generalização e especialização no banco de dados.

Comment: Só para complementar, as entidades filho Pessoa Fisica e Pessoa Jurica tem precisam herdar o id de Pessoa